# Button onclick postback is not working after changed design to bootstrap

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with asp.net 4.0 recently i have changed the design to bootstrap.
From that time the button postback or any postback on that page is not working. I am new to bootstrap
my button design code

```
  <asp:Button ID="addnewaddressbuttons" runat="server" OnClick="addnewaddressbutton_Click" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" Text="Add Address" />
```

code behind:

```
 protected void addnewaddressbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int i = lbj.addnewaddress(Session["emailid"].ToString(), inputaddress.Text, inputlandmark.Text, inputpincode.Text,inputsubarea.Text,"Hyderabad", "Telangana");
    Page_Load(this, null);
    Page.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
}
```

i have also tried

```
   <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <asp:Button ID="addnewaddressbuttons" runat="server" OnClick="addnewaddressbutton_Click" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" Text="Add Address" />

                     </div>
```

and also tried with update panel nothing is working. Please help me

Thank you

Comment: Button in a repeater working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some alternative solution.
it is working i don't the side effects of using it let me know anything
by onserverclick. Postabck is happeninhg but clientside values are not retrieving i intented into insert values into a table. Empty values are inserted everytime with this type of postback

```
<button runat="server" id="sss" onserverclick="addnewaddressbutton_Click" class="btn-buynow"> Add Address</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some solution to the problem .
There is another form in the page it is creating the problem.

```
   <form role="form">
     </form>
```

after deleting this element all postbacks are working fine.
Thank You